# How to access a file server share from an ASP.NET Core web API application published in IIS within the same domain?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, getfiles

I need access to files that are in a files server in my LAN from my Angular app.

I assume that I need to publish my Angular app in the same network, that is, in my IIS Server inside the same LAN

Now on my local machine, I try to access my shared folder \192.168.100.7\OfertasHistoric" but I don´t know how to do it.

When I try this

```
[HttpGet("directorio")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string[]>> GetDirectoryContents()
{
  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\192.168.100.7\ofertashistorico");
  return files;
}
```

I get this error

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Users/kintela/Repos/Intranet-WebAPI/Intranet.API/\192.168.100.7\ofertashistorico'

It seems that the path that you give to the GetFiles method only searches from the current directory where the project is located downwards and I don't know how to indicate a different one.

I also do not know how to manage the issue of the credentials necessary to access said resource

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any concern about this issue ?

Comment: This would work for me on my computer from which I am developing but once I publish this in Azure do I have to force each user to do all this?

Comment: You haven't mentioned `azure` before -_-, pls wait let me try it.

Comment: Where is your share folder ? On premise or azure ? And Can we map it as network drive like below ?

Comment: Tha app will be publisehd in Azure but the shared folder is On Premise and can be mapped as network drive. in fact, all employees have it mapped like this \\fulcrum.local\offers through a dfs route

Answer (score 0):

I am using below code and it works for me. Please check it.

**Steps:**

1. Navigate to the path like : `\\192.168.2.50\ftp`

   [image]
2. Delete `\ftp`, the address in folder explorer should be `\\192.168.2.50`, find the folder you want, right click and map network drive.

   [image]

   [image]
3. You can try it with this address `ftp:\\192.168.2.50`, it will pop up a window. Input you usename and password, then you can check the files.

   [image]

   [image]

#### Test Result

[image]

#### Sample code

```
    [HttpGet("directorio")]
    public IActionResult GetDirectoryContents()
    {
        string networkPath = @"ftp:\\192.168.2.50";
        string userName = @"Administrator";
        string password = "Yy16";

        #region FtpWebRequest
        var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        var uri = new Uri(networkPath);

        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Credentials = networkCredential;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        try
        {
            using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Access to the path '" + networkPath + "' is denied. Error message: " + ex.Message);
        }
        #endregion

        return Ok();
    }
```